# Run macro in another just opened Workbook

Tags: excel, vba

My problem is similar to other problems, but not exactly. The point for the workaround is so that the original file stays intact.

I have Files A and B. Macro in A must:

1. Open B with macro in A (OK)
2. Execute a macro in A that does all the calculations in B (so if the same macro would be run in B there would be no problems)
3. Copy results from B to A
4. Close B without saving
5. Loop for different B and copy all to A

Is this possible or should I tackle this in some other way?

Comment: It is possible. Go for it.

Answer (score 0):

Basic example of how to edit cells in another workbook and copy something from there into this workbook:

```
'open another workbook
Dim wbB As Workbook
Set wbB = Workbooks.Open(FileName:="C:\Temp\WorkbookB.xlsx", ReadOnly:=True)

'change something in that other workbook
wbB.Worksheets("SheetInWorkbookB").Range("A1").Value = "I changed it"

'copy from that other workbook into this workbook
wbB.Worksheets("SheetInWorkbookB").Range("A1:A10").Copy Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Result").Range("A1")

'close that other workbook without saving
wbB.Close SaveChanges:=False
```